# I have to write a method to determine when there cannot be a winner in a game (tie)

Tags: java

> my game is a modified version of (count 4 ) you need 5 in a row not just 4 and the Field is  8*9

```
public static String checkWinner(String[][] field) {
```

> the first type of winning line,
>           a horizontal line
>
> since our X/O/Empty's can only be in odd places,
>               because of how we created the pattern in the first
>               method, then our count has to be incremented by 2
>               and will start from 0 (which will be 1)
>               and stop at 8 (which will be 9)

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j += 2) {
            if ((field[i][j + 1] != " ")
                    && (field[i][j + 3] != " ")
                    && (field[i][j + 5] != " ")
                    && (field[i][j + 7] != " ")
                    && (field[i][j + 9] != " ")
                    && ((field[i][j + 1] == field[i][j + 3])
                    && (field[i][j + 3] == field[i][j + 5])
                    && (field[i][j + 5] == field[i][j + 7])
                    && (field[i][j + 7] == field[i][j + 9])
            )
            )
                return field[i][j + 1];


            //If we found a same pattern, we'll return
            //the  pattern so that we will know who won

        }
    }
```

> For a vertical line, let's first loop over each
>          odd-numbered column by incrementing with 2
>           and check for consecutive boxes in the same column
>          that are the same pattern

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 18; i += 2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if ((field[j][i] != " ")
                    && (field[j + 1][i] != " ")
                    && (field[j + 2][i] != " ")
                    && (field[j + 3][i] != " ")
                    && (field[j + 4][i] != " ")
                    && ((field[j][i] == field[j + 1][i])
                    && (field[j + 1][i] == field[j + 2][i])
                    && (field[j + 2][i] == field[j + 3][i])
                    && (field[j + 3][i] == field[j + 4][i])
            ))

                return field[j][i];
        }
    }
```

> For the left-up to right-down diagonal line

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 18; j += 2) {
            if ((field[i][j] != " ")
                    && (field[i + 1][j + 2] != " ")
                    && (field[i + 2][j + 4] != " ")
                    && (field[i + 3][j + 6] != " ")
                    && (field[i + 4][j + 8] != " ")
                    && ((field[i][j] == field[i + 1][j + 2])
                    && (field[i + 1][j + 2] == field[i + 2][j + 4])
                    && (field[i + 2][j + 4] == field[i + 3][j + 6])
                    && (field[i + 3][j + 6] == field[i + 4][j + 8])))
                return field[i][j];
        }// for  j
    }// for  i,32
```

> Similar to the method above, but we're just reversing our
>           trajectory, i.e. we're starting from the rightmost column
>           instead of the leftmost like we did above

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 9; j < 19; j += 2) {
            if ((field[i][j] != " ")
                    && (field[i + 1][j - 2] != " ")
                    && (field[i + 2][j - 4] != " ")
                    && (field[i + 3][j - 6] != " ")
                    && (field[i + 4][j - 8] != " ")
                    && ((field[i][j] == field[i + 1][j - 2])
                    && (field[i + 1][j - 2] == field[i + 2][j - 4])
                    && (field[i + 2][j - 4] == field[i + 3][j - 6])
                    && (field[i + 3][j - 6] == field[i + 4][j - 8])))
                return field[i][j];
        }// for j

    }// for  i

    //If after going over the table and we find no
    //same pattern lines, then we have to return something
    //that says that we didn't find a winner :P
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I would think that you would want to see if player 1 'wins', treating spaces as player 1 tokens. Repeat for player 2.

Comment: I see some more things you might want to change...  It appears you are comparing strings using `==`. This is bad in that it will work 'sometimes'.  Use the String.equals() method instead - as in, `field[i][j+1].equals(field[i][j+3])`,  Also, if you are making sure that `field[i][j+1]` is not a space, and that `field[i][j+3]` equals `field[i][j+1]`, then you do not also need to make sure that `field[i][j+3]` is not a space.

Comment: you have right . Thank you

Comment: I want a methode to determine when it is impossible for any player to win , before the game ends